# NodeJS Cluster management

Tags: node.js

I want to use Cluster module in NodeJS to automatically scale my applications processes in case of load.

1. So, I would like to detect how much requests are getting in or in queue to process.
2. If they are hanging for long, then I would want to fork new sub processes to help out with load.
3. As the load goes down, it automatically tears down the extra sub processes.

In order to do this, I want to know how many concurrent connections are created or how many of them are in queue. I used server.getConnections but with in cluster it just comes out to be 2 mostly, I am assuming it is just receiving two request and rest of them are still with master.

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: Are you being charged dynamically for the extra processes?  If not, then just spin up the extra ones all the time and let them handle some of the load, even when things aren't busy.

Comment: The scheme here [Building A Node.JS Server That Won't Melt](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/01/building-a-node-js-server-that-wont-melt-a-node-js-holiday-season-part-5/) uses a measurement of average request latency which is probably ultimately what you care about.  When latency goes above some amount, you want to spin up more processes.

Comment: So, the problem with cluster is as soon as i spin up more sub processes, it consumes the memory for a complete new process. So, in comparison to having a new instance of node itself may in a container or something i am not getting any additional benefit. So, thats why i wanted to experiment with cluster where I can see on run time if i need more instances only then i spin up more else I just keep it low. Since I would want to be more optimized in my memory footprint too.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me.  You either have enough memory for more than one process or you don't.